# How to upgrade a laravel project to use angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have a static Laravel Project and want to use Angular with it. How can I do that? Is there a step-by-step tutorial, because i'm not familiar with gulp, bower, etc. I found https://www.laravel-angular.io/#/ but it seems like this only works for new projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel no need to upgare for this.
you use angular in blade.
For this purpose use `@` before `{{ variable }}`
for example

```
Hello, @{{ name }}.
```

return

```
Hello, {{ name }}
```

the `@` symbol will be removed by Blade; however, {{ name }} expression will remain untouched by the Blade engine, allowing it to instead be rendered by your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just add and include angular library in your blade template, like any other javascript library and start using it.

Comment: Doesn't Angular also `uses {{ }}`? I've seen that Blade can also use 3 curly braces to not interfere but this would be way to much work to change it.

Comment: Yes angular uses {{ }}. To tell laravel not to interfare with angular, you can use @{{ }} in blade views, it will tell Laravel not to interfare with that variable.

Comment: Thank you @Nabeel. Managed to get Angular working like this. However I got another problem, maybe you could take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873801/angular-module-maincontroller-is-not-available Thank you!

Comment: @Scarwolf my answer solves your original issue. You should accept it :)